# Having an issue with the visual studio console

Tags: visual-studio

Why does my visual studio 2017 exit the project console as soon as it starts.
It shows me the console but it closes just after it appears.
I've read some of the answers here but it didn't help me.
This is the output screen:

```
'Project4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Project4\Debug\Project4.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Project4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The program '[7192] Project4.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Use `Ctrl+F5` to run the code then it will stay open

Answer (score 0):

In the end of your code (main method) use

```
char a;
std::cin >> a;
```

that's wait to type something and then close cmd(terminal)

Comment: thank you amin, actually after reading a lot of the problems here I found out that it was a project properties issue and the solution was to make it console from the project properties window.    thanks a lot.

Comment: Your welcome If you want to help other people have the same problem.write the answer I like to know solution.